# Lost files saved in Windows partition while working in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-transfer

I have dual booted my system with Ubuntu and Windows 8. When I was working in Ubuntu, I saved some files onto the Windows data partition. Well it normally exists. But I booted into windows and then back into Ubuntu and the files are gone. 
What problem is this? Can I find my files back?

Comment: Was Windows in hibernation when you wrote the files from Ubuntu? If so, that would be the cause, because the file system would still be open in Windows, and it cannot accept changes made from "outside".

Comment: No I had completely shut down the windows system. Is it possible that the filesystem hadn't yet updated the change and thus cannot read it? If so can I access it somehow??

Comment: Well the files are not visible on the explorer however I can find it through shell commands. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Command Prompt you can use the copy command and attempt to copy the files elsewhere. More information about the copy command is available [here](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html). If copying the files to another place on your Windows partition doesn't work, try copying them to your Ubuntu partition.

If you mean't the terminal in Ubuntu you can visit this [site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) for more information.